# using AWS SNS to send SMS

Tags: sms, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

For one of my clients I have AWS SNS set up for Push Notifications to IOS and Android devices.  Another client wants SMS messages to phone numbers.  I see that AWS SNS supports sending SMS messages, this new client only has an AWS account they don't have an Apple account or Google account.  So ...

Do I need to create applications with the endpoints for those two services to send SMS messages?  Which means setting up the Apple Accounts and Google Accounts?  How does AWS know which provider to send the SMS message to?  With SNS sends I had the device ID from the mobile app to identify the type.

Sorry if I am rambling but I appreciate any insight on this.

Comment: why is this question down voted? i see no problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to send SMS messages, you can do it directly from Amazon SNS.

Here is an example using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws sns publish --phone-number +61123456789 --message 'Success!'
```

The phone number is in international format, starting with the country code.

See: [SNS publish — AWS CLI 1.15.12 Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/publish.html)

You can also send it programmatically by using an SDK for programming languages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I want to send a SMS via the AWS SDK and I have found the publish method to that no problem there.  BUT , I still don't know how it sends SMS messages, do I need to setup accounts with GCM (Google Cloud Messenger) and Apple Push Notification (APN) to send a SMS text message the SAME way that I did to send a SNS notification message

Comment: No. The above method (via CLI or SDK) does not require any Apple/Android setup. It sends direct from SNS to SMS.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.  It works great.  Really is very easy once e everything is configured.  Thanks again.